# Endpoint not found from a docker container

Tags: docker, rest, docker-compose, endpoint

I have a service container in docker which works fine, however when I am testing it with postman, it cannot find one particular endpoint and throws 404 not found error, I thought it could be because of the @Profile annotation, so I removed it and ran the container again, however, it is still unable to find it. What could be the reason for this? All my controllers are identical with the same annotations.
For the reference these are above the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/phone-numbers")
```

And this is above my method

```
@GetMapping("/verification-code/{phoneNumber}")
```

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Spring